# Zsh Terminal not registering changes made to zshrc

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I wanted to change the theme of my *oh my zsh* terminal in the .zshrc-file. When I tried to do that it didn't register and gave me an Error-message which I wasn't able to reproduce. Now I just have this weird Lock in my Terminal. Does somebody knows what it means / how I can get rid of it?

[Zsh Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMpDe.png)

Comment: What changes have you made in `.zshrc`? Mac related questions are better suitable for [apple.se].

Comment: I tried to add ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX="true" which is a bug workaround I need

Comment: @Phil : The error message means that some command (perhaps `tput`) is asking for a [termcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap) entry which macos does not understand. If you do get a working shell at least, you could source the .zshrc manually with `set -x` turned on, to see at which point the problem occurs.

Comment: @user1934428 It's a `terminfo` entry (because that's what `echoti` deals with) and it is the _terminal_ (not the OS) that is reported as not understanding it.

Comment: @Phil It looks like the contents of your `$terminfo` array don't match with what `echoti` reports. What other changes have you made to your `~/.zshrc` file? Have you perhaps redefined the `$terminfo` array? What version of Zsh are you using? And how exactly have you tried to change your theme?

Comment: @MarlonRichert I'm using oh-my-zsh to change the theme and did that by changing the ZSH-THEME="agnoster".

Comment: @MarlonRichert I also didn't change anything to the ```$terminfo```... I can't even find that in my RC.

Comment: @Phil Can you share your `.zshrc` file via Pastebin, GitHub Gist, Hastebin or a similar site? Then I can have a look at it.

Comment: Also, the question marks in your prompt mean that you are not using a Powerline font in your terminal. I recommend using Fira Code: https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode

Comment: @Marlon Richert Here you go: https://gist.github.com/PythonPhil-crack/d06adaf4ac947304a31fd4ab4c9195e5

Comment: @Phil You're missing a `#` [on line 9](https://gist.github.com/PythonPhil-crack/d06adaf4ac947304a31fd4ab4c9195e5#file-zshrc-L9) causing that line to be interpreted as shell code, rather than as a comment.

Comment: I think that was just a mistake when copying the file. In my rc that part is also commented out